# "nobody could beat me" vs "anybody could beat me"

Tags: word-choice, negation

This is a part of translation work that I am doing.

> 1. Let everyone declare that I am defeated, until I concede defeat, nowhere, ever, **anyone/anybody** could beat me.

Is the bold part correct in the above sentence, or should I replace it with ***nobody***, as follows:

> 2. Let everyone declare that I am defeated, until I concede defeat, nowhere, ever, **nobody** could beat me.

Comment: Semantically speaking, *let everyone declare I'm defeated, until I concede defeat* doesn't make sense. So, only *before* you concede defeat should they declare you're defeated—and then, presumably, once you *do* concede defeat they should *stop* declaring you defeated?

Comment: The cited context is difficult to make sense of, and so "non-idiomatically" expressed it's hard to see how it can be treated as anything other than proofreading

Comment: @FumbleFingers The asker has identified a specific source of concern, so this isn't proofreading. cheng: Because it's not clear what the rest of the sentence says, it's difficult to answer your question. Please [edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/191699/edit) your post to include additional details or restate the sentence using different words.

Comment: You are translating into English? Usually, one translates into one's native language. That said "Let everyone declare" sounds really odd to me. The use of exhortatory language is rare in English except in poetry or religion: Let us pray. Let freedom ring.

Comment: @cheng - I deleted your “Thanks for all the replies” comment. [Here’s why](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/are-thanks-for-the-answers-unnecessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this right, there is a misunderstanding about the use of the initial word, "Let".

Did you perhaps mean to use "Let" in the sense of a rhetorical "stipulation"?

I.e.: "for the sake of argument, *let* it be supposed that ...", and then the following statements will proceed from that hypothetical premise. Indeed this is a valid use of the word "let" in cold, logical math proofs and TV courtroom dramas, etc. (Let x be a real number greater than zero....)

But "let" can also be used to express a fervent wish or prayer, as in "Let freedom ring!" Your whole statement has the force of an emotionally charged proclamation, and when we hear, "Let everyone declare ..." we understand "let" in this latter, "exhortative" meaning. It sounds like you are urging "everyone" to declare you defeated.

I think what you mean to say is, "Even though everyone *may* declare that I am defeated ...."

With that correction, your dramatic exclamation sounds more reasonable.

> Even though everyone may declare that I am defeated, until I concede defeat, ...

[I am unbeatable].

There are a couple ways to express that you are unbeatable. You could use *either* "anyone"/"anybody" *or* "nobody", but the verb tense sounds more defiant and forceful with "can" [indicative, factual] rather than "could" [conditional, "iffy"].

Either:

> Even though everyone may declare that I am defeated, until I concede defeat, nowhere, ever, can anyone [or anybody] beat me.

or:

> Even though everyone may declare that I am defeated, until I concede defeat, nobody, anywhere, ever can beat me.

But you do want to avoid using a double negative ("nowhere, ever, nobody could beat me" isn't good in English.)

Comment: Hello, the "Let" in this case is as you said, "let it be supposed that". No, it's not a wish or prayer. "Even though everyone may declare that I am defeated ...." is better than my sentence beginning with let. Also I will use, "Even though everyone may declare that I am defeated, until I concede defeat, nowhere, ever, can anyone [or anybody] beat me." as you advised. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @cheng , Sorry to be obvious, but just to clarify: "anyone [or "anybody"] are two separate alternatives to choose from. Of course you don't want to include both words. (But you know that....)